# Eploring Google Chart Image API

Tags: google-visualization

I have following chart http://bit.ly/WXn4kb at my Appengine dashboard.

- Am I right that image API is deprecated? If yes, which settings should I use to draw similar chart using new API?
- Is there any service to see decoded chart params?
- How can I use relative dates (-1d) in charts?